# How New Bitcoin Addresses not using Signature ? Only witness or Very Short Signature?

Tags: signature

I have Noticed Something strange to me
Newly Used Bitcoin Addresses show repeated very short Signatures
and Multiple Witness ??
and Some not even any signature for the transaction ?
what is happening actually ?

example : https://blockchain.info/de/rawaddr/3BMEXokv2vPoEKPn7YWEhXoPYyZuzauLXJ

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that API is just simply broken. If you look at the [web page results](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3BMEXokv2vPoEKPn7YWEhXoPYyZuzauLXJ) (or a [different blockchain explorer's API](https://blockstream.info/api/address/3BMEXokv2vPoEKPn7YWEhXoPYyZuzauLXJ/txs) for that address, all of script and witness information is presented correctly.